# Using textboxes to search entries based on a keyword (There are multiple textboxes for separate entities) and implementing a combo box

Tags: ms-access, combobox, textbox, vba, multi-select

I want to be able to enter in a keyword into a textbox that would search records for that keyword and present reports based on that word that are found.

**Please Note:** There are multiple textboxes for this to separate specific information so that I need this to work for each individual textbox. There is one text box that will search for entries based on the date (month/day/year) and I have been having issues with it not displaying certain date ranges.

I am also looking to add in a combo box as well.

I have tried code that another individual has given me, but the issue that I have run into with the normal textboxes is that it requires me to put in everything that is in the entry as opposed to search based on a keyword to which nothing pops up when other criteria have been put in place (I know that there is an entry that fits, but for some reason when I add in the textbox element it does not work unless I put in the exact entry that is in the textbox that I am search the specific information from).

I have been trying to find information for combo boxes, but I have not found anything that really works with what I want to do.

```vb
Function SelectedItems(objBox As ListBox) As String
    Dim strRtn As String, varItm
    For Each varItm In objBox.ItemsSelected
        strRtn = strRtn & ",'" & objBox.ItemData(varItm) & "'"
    Next varItm
    If strRtn <> vbNullString Then SelectedItems = Mid(strRtn, 2)
End Function
Private Sub Command62_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strArr As String
    Dim varItm

    For Each varItm In Array("District", "Circumstance", "Location", "Method", "Point", "Rank", "Description", "Missing", "IDNumber", "Dateto", "Datefrom", "Address")
        strArr = vbNullString
        Select Case Me.Controls(varItm).ControlType
            Case acListBox
                strArr = SelectedItems(Me.Controls(varItm))
            Case acTextBox
                If Not IsNull(Me.Controls(varItm).Value) Then
                    strArr = "'" & Me.Controls(varItm).Value & "'"
                End If
        End Select
        If strArr <> vbNullString Then
            strSQL = strSQL & "t." & varItm & " in (" & strArr & ") and "
        End If
    Next varItm
    If strSQL <> vbNullString Then strSQL = "where " & Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 5)

    With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryMultiselect")
        .SQL = "select * from tblDataEntry t " & strSQL
    End With
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryMultiselect"
End Sub
```

What I want is to be able to use my multi-select listboxes in conjunction with my textboxes as well as my combo box that I have as well. Using all of that or at least a combination of them, I want to be able to sort through my data to be able to create reports based on what is being looked for. Along with making sure that the user has the freedom to not having to enter in information for all fields and only the ones that they feel they need to enter in information on.

With the textboxes: I want to be able to search based on a keywords that corresponds with a specific section of the data that I am looking for and to be able to leave others blank and be able to pull up results.

The same goes for the date/time textboxes and my combo box.

Comment: Well, somewhere in code probably have to build criteria that uses LIKE and * wildcard. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: @HansUp Like this?

SELECT *
FROM tblDataEntry AS t
WHERE t.District in ('City') and t.Description in ('couple');

This is what I get when I run the query. What happens is that when I add in the entry for the textbox ('couple'), it displays no results. So I'm trying to figure out why that is or at least where I could put in a LIKE and * wildcard.

Comment: There is, but the word 'couple' is a part of the entry in there.

Comment: It would, but the way that my function works is that it needs to be done in VBA where all of it is conducted on a form on access and I make selections on a multi-select listbox and enter in a keyword or phrase into the corresponding textbox and press a button that generates the report. So I could put that down, but it would only be temporary as the SQL statement resets every time I do something different on the form.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: I have been trying to change the code where I could have a wildcard where it would (hopefully) work out like that, but whenever I put it in where I think it would go there is always an error that pops up so I'm not sure where it is supposed to go in my code.

Comment: This is an example that I am very familiar with and tried to understand. However, because of how the code is structured it does not help to explain how I would be able to fix my code or at least a starting point of where it could be changed.